# Combinations of restricted set of integers

Tags: python, combinations

How to generate the list of combinations with `allowed_ints` that sums to `goal` ?

Examples:

```
allowed_ints=[1,2], goal=4
combinations = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,1,1],[2,2],[1,2,1]]

allowed_ints=[5, 6], goal=13
combinations =  []
```

What I've made so far don't works.

```
def combinations(allowed_ints, goal):
    if goal > 0:
        for i in allowed_ints:
            for p in combinations(allowed_ints, goal-i):
                yield [i] + p
    else:
        yield []

print list(combinations([1, 2],3))
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]] # not what I want
```

Comment: check that you don't cross the threshold for `goal`.

Comment: After a complete run of combinations() ?

Comment: You could, but why postpone the task...

Comment: don't know how to include it in the recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using you function try this:

```
def combinations(allowed_ints, goal):
    if goal > 0:
        for i in allowed_ints:
            for p in combinations(allowed_ints, goal-i):
                if sum([i] + p) == goal:
                    yield [i] + p
    else:
        yield []

print list(combinations([1, 2],3))
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already selected an answer, but I wanted to offer an alternative that's not as similar to your code. If you wanted to use recursion, I would suggest something like this:

```
def combinations(allowed_ints, list, goal):
    # base case: you're done
    if sum(list) == goal:
        print list
    # if overshoot, stop here
    elif sum(list) > goal:
        pass
    else:
        for i in allowed_ints:
            new_list = list[:]
            new_list.append(i)
            combinations(allowed_ints, new_list, goal)

combinations([1, 2],[],4)
```

It's no better than the suggested answer, but uses a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

You should include 3 conditions like

goal == 0 then recursion worked

goal < 0 then recursion failed

goal >= 0 and list elements end then recursion failed

By the way you can do it all using recursion. No need of loop, recursion can also do loop

Comment: I don't who marked my answer as down. I have written the coin combination program in Scala, which finds the unique combination. 

In fact the above program is giving duplicate responses as in 1,2 and 2,1 are same